# cosmic vega 8 screen flicker/glitches

Tags: radeon, amd-graphics, flicker

I've an Lenovo yoga 530 notebook. It has an AMD Ryzen 2500u with vega8 graphics integrated.
For getting the touchscreen and mousepad working I had to install the kernel module from here:
[MP2 I2C controller driver](https://github.com/Syniurge/i2c-amd-mp2)

For wifi I need this kernel module:
[Realtek RTL8821CE Driver](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce)

Now that I have the touchscreen & pad working with some issues sometimes, and the wifi works, but isn't perfect aswell, I'm having still trouble with my screen:

The built in screen is flickering like in the video linked below. But it's not always the same position or frequency. Some combinations of programs or the position on the screen affects the flicker frequency and position. E.g. changing the zoom on a pdf just a little bit, can bring the flicker frequency from nearly nothing to nearly always present.

Apart from that I recognized that the background diashow I set is working fine on the internal screen, but if have an additonal external monitor connected, the switch to the next picture mixes both pictures up^^.

Anyone knows a fix to this, or has an idea/tip what to do?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 using Cinnamon desktop atm. (But the issue is on Ubuntus standard desktop, too.

[Screen Flicker Video download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulbqo7taspx60vv/VID_20190123_151449.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124253/missing-firmware-for-amdgpu

Comment: Indeed there were files in the linked git repo I hadn't locally, but it didn't fix the flickering :/