# Missing firmware and virtual box

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualbox

```
sudo apt -y upgrade
```

The warnings:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run 
/sbin/vboxconfig as root.  If your system is using EFI Secure Boot you may need to sign 
the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you 
can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: For firmware take a look https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124253/missing-firmware-for-amdgpu