# Is it possible to fix the possible missing firmware (see picture below) after installing Kernel 5.4.0-48 to Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kernel, firmware, i915

I saw the previous questions on Possible missing firmware but in my case, I got few more than previously reported. See picture below.
I installed this kernel:

5.4.0-48-generic #52~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 12:50:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I upgraded the kernel with the hope to solve a flickering screen problem during boot time but also the problem of a black screen (failure to boot). I tried all the listed solutions on these two problems and they did not work for me. So I upgraded the kernel and now it boots on the first try (not the 2nd or 3rd) but the flickering is still there and it takes a lot less time to boot. It doesn't really bother me. I am hoping that the problem will be resolved one day after an update.

I searched for the missing files in the firmware site from a linked question but couldn't find the versions of the missing files referenced in the picture below.

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/amdgpu

I don't have a problem with identifying this post as a duplicate and closing it.

During that install, I got the error in the picture.

[image: this is the warning when upgrading to Kernel 5.0]

Comment: I am not comfortable with Linux. I had experienced a problem with flickering of the screen during boot. Many times, I had to cycle through the power before booting. I tried many listed solutions here and elsewhere but not one worked for me. I found the info on the new kernel and I thought it would help my problem. I cannot post the text because I no longer have it. Sorry about that.
Sorry I added the exact name of the kernel I installed 5.4.0-48.

Comment: My mistake, I just added the exact number of the kernel in the post and in my comment. Sorry again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing firmware for amdgpu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124253/missing-firmware-for-amdgpu)

Comment: There is nothing to fix, but you can if you like.

Comment: @Pilot6, I don't have an amd gpu. I have an integrated Intel graphic card. I searched for the missing files rtl_nic, i915...(I don't have a clue what they are needed for) on the firmware site you gave and did not find a single instance. Maybe it's hidden 10 layers below the surface. So I am not inclined to go through the procedure. 
I will add that after I upgraded the kernel to 5.4.0-48, the flickering is still there but I no longer have to cycle through the power few times. It's booting the 1st time but it takes longer than usual.

Comment: @Pilot6, if there is nothing to fix, why was it complaining? Can you please give me an idea of the nature of the files it complained about (rtl_nic, i915) so I know what the real nature of the problem is. thanks.

Comment: I gave a link to a similar issue. This is about an Intel one. If you don't have one of the mentioned Intel devices, it is irrelevant for you. But if the message bothers you, you can get mainline `linux-firmware` and add these files.