# System freeze during lid-close induced suspension, amdgpu cries "page fault"

Tags: drivers, kernel, suspend, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm using kernel 5.9.1 with amd 4500U which has its integrated graphics.

If I close the lid and open it again, it freezes. This doesn't happen if I choose to suspend from the menu.
After a forced restart, I'm inspecting the syslog

I see these entries, I don't know if they indicate "going to sleep" or indicate "waking from sleep"

```
 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
 kernel: [ 7845.129317] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
 systemd-sleep[31070]: Suspending system...
 kernel: [ 7845.145889] Filesystems sync: 0.016 seconds
 kernel: [ 7845.275516] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
 kernel: [ 7845.279846] OOM killer disabled.
```

Then I get to these

```
kernel: [ 7848.374310] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32769, for process Xorg pid 1519 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1682)
kernel: [ 7848.374313] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:   in page starting at address 0x0000800111801000 from client 27
kernel: [ 7848.374315] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: VM_L2_PROTECTION_FAULT_STATUS:0x00501031
kernel: [ 7848.374316] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:      Faulty UTCL2 client ID: 0x8
kernel: [ 7848.374318] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:      MORE_FAULTS: 0x1
kernel: [ 7848.374319] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:      WALKER_ERROR: 0x0
kernel: [ 7848.374320] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:      PERMISSION_FAULTS: 0x3
kernel: [ 7848.374321] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:      MAPPING_ERROR: 0x0
kernel: [ 7848.374323] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu:      RW: 0x0
kernel: [ 7848.374332] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: [gfxhub0] retry page fault (src_id:0 ring:0 vmid:5 pasid:32769, for process Xorg pid 1519 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1682)
```

I'm using the default drives that come with the kernel release. What's wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: This seems to have helped https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124253/missing-firmware-for-amdgpu . I'll see if the system stays stable for a few days, and if it does I'll expand this comment into a full answer.