# possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/

Tags: suspend, hp, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I have a HP envy x360 with ryzen 3500u and Whenever I run apt upgrade I get following warnings.
My laptop also doesn't wake from suspend, can these be related, and how can I solve them?

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven2_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/picasso_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/oland_uvd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/pitcairn_uvd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/verde_uvd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/tahiti_uvd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_dmcu.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navy_flounder_dmcub.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_dmcub.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_dmcub.bin for module amdgpu
```

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124253/missing-firmware-for-amdgpu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing firmware for amdgpu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124253/missing-firmware-for-amdgpu)

Comment: Did you find them?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone still looking into this because suspend/sleep is not working on their ryzen laptops, this is an issue which has still not been solved fully, but you can read more in detail about it [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230)