# Old Radeon GPU on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, radeon

I wanted to ask you since it's well known fact that old Radeon GPUs work well on 16.04,
what needs to be done to make it work on 20.04 ? I've got rather old AMD Radeon R9 supposedly with 2GB which still can be good for basic computing. On the AMD support page I've found appropriate drivers however they require dependencies 20.04 doesn't come with.

The reason why I don't want to stick with open source drivers is that the rendering
isn't good. I can use the computer but using proper drivers would allow for nice rendering
of details and pixels plus I would get proper resolution for the monitor out of the box without having to do any hackery in the terminal.

I know I can switch to Windows and it will install the drivers automatically, but I use Ubuntu for reason.

Any advice on how should I proceed ?

Comment: The R9 is a GCN card and should work out of the box in Ubuntu 18.04 or newer, without a need to install any driver. Did you actually try running the LiveUSB installation? Or are you experiencing an actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Take a look at this ppa: [https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade</del>

Yes sorry I was too hasty. Perhaps this was already answered here:

[enable AMDGPU for R9 270x on 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372707/enable-amdgpu-for-r9-270x-on-20-04)

Comment: It says the repo doesn't have a release file and therefore disabled.

Comment: The notes for this PPA is pretty clear about which releases are supported: 22.04 and 22.10. Unfortunately this answer cannot solve the OP’s problem.